# How to know if a task has exited?

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am using the following code snippet in my project,

```
mutex_lock(&driver->diag_file_mutex);
if (driver->md_session_map[peripheral] &&
    driver->md_session_map[peripheral]->task) {
    stat = send_sig_info(info.si_signo, &info,
                 driver->md_session_map[peripheral]->task);
}
mutex_unlock(&driver->diag_file_mutex);
```

In this particular scenario, some other process is freeing up the  driver->md_session_map[peripheral]->task (The memory dump of the task is 0x6B6B6B6B signifying the page has been freed and code in my execution path is not freeing up prior), resulting in kernel panic.

The check in 'if' condition is of no use since value is 0x6B6B6B6B. Mutex is serving no purpose too.

Is there a way to check in if condition if task is freed up or a way to notify my driver if freed. help is gravely needed.

Comment: What type of `driver` variable is?

Comment: its of type struct diagchar_dev, defined in https://us.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18/tree/drivers/char/diag/diagchar.h?h=LA.HB.1.1.1.c2

Comment: If a task has opened the device, you should get a `release` call when the device is closed (and hence you would be notified prior to the task exiting). If the task hasn't opened the device, it would be dangerous to keep a reference to the task (at least without some other means to ensure the driver gets notified on task exit). There is no reliable way to check whether a task has exited solely from the task structure pointer once that has been freed.

Comment: I guess that your code should hold the `&driver->md_session_lock` mutex while using `driver->md_session_map`.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the suggestion.